# Drywall Bathroom Mounting: How to move mirror clip up

Tags: bathroom, drywall, repair, mounting, mirror

I bought some 1/4 inch mirror clips. I installed one them tad bit low (so the mirror is little bit smashed/warped) because it has to bend/curve to meet the lower height. How do I raise the hole higher? I don't think I have enough space to drill the hole little bit up, or it'll make larger hole. Is there any special clip or tool which will fix this issue?  Looking for a longer 1/4 inch mirror clip maybe.

Here is mirror and above is light fixture panel.

[image]

Bought these mirror clips: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Style-Selections-Plastic-Mirror-Clips/1056913

Just fyi: Its sitting on a splashguard mounting system.  https://www.lowes.com/pd/Gardner-Glass-Products-Metal-Mirror-Mounting-System/50098568

[image]

Are there any kind of adjustable mirror clips which would solve this issue, so if it happens again, its adjustable? Maybe this, however these will not work as they fit behind the mirror.

[image]

Comment: Can you move it sideways a bit to avoid a double sized hole?

Comment: I think I can do that move sideways, @crip659 also I just posted a product that may solve the issue? would that work?  thanks https://www.lowes.com/pd/Hillman-4-Count-Wide-Channel-Mirror-Clips/3384476

Comment: They should since they are height adjustable, but the screw looks like it fits behind the mirror, instead of above it.  Might make life more fun fitting the mirror in.

Comment: How many clips are on the top of the mirror? Your picture implies a single clip in the center. Generally, just increase or decrease the number of clips you're using by one, which will result in new/different locations for the clips, but still leave the clips positioned symmetrically. That's almost certainly going to look better than to *only* move one clip a bit, which would result in a non-symmetrical placement.

Comment: hi @Makyen I have two clips at the top, 36 by 36 mirror, and a rail at the bottom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the clip sideways a bit, an inch if you can.

This will be enough to not make a bigger hole, since imagine the height difference needed is quite small, less than the hole size needed.

The other clips you mention should work, if you leave them a tiny bit loose, just enough to move the clips up by hand.  Place the mirror and push the clips down again.